# HSQLDB in embedded mode when database file path has spaces

Tags: windows, file, jdbc, path, hsqldb

The HSQLDB documentation says something to the effect of:

> Special care may be needed w.r.t. file path specifications containing whitespace, mixed-case, special characters and/or reserved file names.  Please read your OS file system documentation.

However, they provide ZERO documentation or examples on the syntax for actually using file names with reserved characters or spaces.  When I use a file name with a space in it, HSQLDB appears to simply hang my entire application.

I've tried escaping with URL syntax ("%20") which does not work because HSQLDB interprets that literally.  I've tried surrounding various portions of the JDBC URL with single and double quotes.  Most result in a failure to access the database error.  At least they don't simply hang.

Does anyone know the proper way to reference an embedded HSQLDB file when the file path has spaces?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you refer to "an embedded HSQLDB file"? "Embedded" in what?

Comment: HSQLDB runs in either "server" or "embedded" file mode.  I was referring to the embedded file mode.

Answer (score 1):

> When I use a file name with a space in it, HSQLDB appears to simply hang my entire application.

For what it's worth, my Windows (Vista) test box has no problems with spaces in the database path or the database name

```java
String connStr = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/Public/test/HSQLDB test/my db";
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr, "sa", "")) {
```

results in this

[image: hsqldb.png]

Tested using hsqldb-2.3.1.

Comment: What if you try the same thing, but put the login parameters in the connStr versus passing them separately to the DriverManager call?  Does that work?

Comment: @robross0606 Yes. `"jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/Public/test/HSQLDB test/my db;user=sa;password="` followed by `DriverManager.getConnection(connStr)` works for me as well.